# OS X Mountain Lion: Change resolution automatically when on battery

Tags: macbook-pro, resolution, power-management

I have a rMBP running OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion.

I normally use the display at a 1680x1050. Is there a way to have the display automatically change resolution to the default retina when on battery, and revert to 1680x1050 when power is reconnected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/) (free) to detect when the power source has switched, and then fire off a shell script to change the resolution.

There's no built-in command line utility for changing the screen resolution, but [someone came up with one](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110830215724984) that works well. You can download an installer [here](http://www.johnford.info/screenresolution-1.4.dmg).

Then it's just a simple matter of setting ControlPlane to run `screenresolution set 1440x900` or `1650x1050` as appropriate. Note that you may want to experiment with the `screenresolution get` command first to double check how it handles retina resolutions.

Comment: ControlPane's 'about' page says it supports Snow Leopard through Lion. While I can check this out myself, but do you know if works well with Mountain Lion as well.

Comment: okay, reading more through the app's website, and I see mountain lion mentioned in a couple of places. so ML seems supported (the developer probably forgot to update he about page). 
the app looks really nifty, thanks for pointing it out!